# SQL Server 2012 Encryption

Tags: sql-server, encryption

Looking for some best practices and help with Encryption.

I've got a customer table which contains names, address and contact info.

It now has over 15000 records and I want to either encrypt the entire table (12 Columns) or should I just encrypt certain columns?

What kind of performance hit are we talking about?

Also how do I do this on a production database?

step by step would be great.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with sensitive information (For example if you are working on Bank customer data) then encrypting the entire table would be best practice. Otherwise you can encrypt sensitive information such as Name, Address,email Id,Acc No etc. Encrypting CustId is not necessary since it doesnt give any sense and besides it will be referred by many child tables. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You should encrypt the entire database, using [Transparent Database Encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx). TDE is, as the name suggests, completely transparent and requires absolutely no changes to your app. Is also very performant. It is an Enterprise Edition feature.

For a shoestring budget you would have to use column level encryption, see [Encrypt a Column of Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331.aspx). Column level encryption has serious impact on your application as your code has to accomodate the fact that column encrypted data cannot be searched, see [Searching Encrypted Data](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lcris/archive/2005/12/22/506931.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to hash (i.e. one way encrypt) the information that is required for **validation only** - i.e. passwords/credit card numbers and provide SSL access to the rest.